# Indexing a dataset with labels in weka arff files

Tags: java, class, indexing, weka, label

I am trying to indexing my dataset in arff files with label indexes. I ve got a dataset of mxn dimension which nth column is dedicated to dataset labels. When I am trying to create arff file I am using weka's class Attribute in order to construct proper the arff file.

```
           int numAtts = data[0].length;                
           FastVector atts = new FastVector(numAtts);

            for (int att = 0; att < numAtts-1; att++) {
                atts.addElement(new weka.core.Attribute("Attribute" + att, att));
            }
            String qwer ="class";
            double [] labels = {1, 2, 3m};

            weka.core.Attribute object = new weka.core.Attribute(qwer);
            atts.addElement(object);
```

My problem is how to construct the last attribute which is labels indexing in arff file in order to take properly a string name "class" and values {1,2,3}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen for instance in [Adding attributes to a dataset](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Adding+attributes+to+a+dataset), the following code should be enough:

```
atts.addElement(new Attribute("class",labels));
```

Where `labels` is of type: `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`

Comment: Unfortunately Weka Attribute doesn't have a constructor Attribute(String, List)

Comment: It has it in the development version at least: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#Attribute(java.lang.String, java.util.List)